# How to record html canvas animation as screenshots without playing the full animation on canvas? Any javascript library for this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, canvas

I am working on an academic project in which I am making a PHP project that is similar to a website https://promo.com/. This website edit videos by embedding overlay text effects on them. I made a website in which there is an overlay canvas section over the video section and I can take screenshots of canvas animation on video and then these screenshots of  "Text animation" are merged as a gif and then I combine the gif and video (all this is done by FFmpeg);and the final product is a video having an overlay text animation. I take screenshots by using the code :

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var png    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

But if the video size is 10 mins long then I have to wait for almost 10 mins so that this code in setInterval can take screenshots after every 50ms. Is that there is some library to accomplish this screenshot taking task of canvas animation so that the screenshots of text animation can be captured without playing them from start to end? I don't know what trick the [promo.com](https://www.promo.com) website is using to record overlay text on video!

> I want that I can record canvas animation as array of images without playing the whole canvas animation. Please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of first creating a canvas and then extracting images from it, You should use the video element directly. I am saying this because seeking from canvas is not in your hand, but seeking from video is. Use javascript along with setinterval both to seek the video forward 50 milisecond and capture the video's thumbnail in each milisecond, this just reduced your time by 5000 times! Here is an example:

```js
// global or parent scope of handlers
var video = document.getElementById("video"); // added for clarity: this is needed
var i = 0;

video.addEventListener('loadeddata', function() {
    this.currentTime = i;
});
video.addEventListener('seeked', function() {

  // now video has seeked and current frames will show
  // at the time as we expect
  generateThumbnail(i);

  // when frame is captured, increase here by 5 seconds
  i += 5;

  // if we are not past end, seek to next interval
  if (i <= this.duration) {
    // this will trigger another seeked event
    this.currentTime = i;
  }
  else {
    // Done!, next action
  }
});
```

Otherwise, if it is absolutely necessary to add a canvas before, then you should create another video tag with the same source link, and hide it using css. Then you will create a javascript function which will seek it to every 5th second programmatically and keep saving the thumbnails and adding them in your container. This way, your thumbnails will be generated for the whole video without loading the whole video.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have to use canvas because there is a text animation on canvas that I need to capture. My question is if I play canvas in the background even then I have to wait until the canvas animation ends. Is there another way that I can capture canvas animation fastly than it takes actual time to complete animation?

Comment: Please try promo.com site , they place text on videos that is editable and then as a final product user get a video with customized text overlay it. I do not know how they are capturing text animation on video. There is not need to take screenshots of video because that is stored on server . The think the text animation that user selects for it.